# Specify items per page

Tags: api, limit, picasa

I'm trying to query Picasa Web Albums to pull album/photo data (obviously!) however initially I only need to pull the first 4 photos. Is there any way to limit a particular field or specify the items per page?

I've already accomplished something similar with Facebook's Graph API however I'm unable to find anything similar for Picasa. The only items I can find related to limiting the response is specifying which fields, but nothing related to the number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use max-results argument. See doc here. 
https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/reference#Parameters

Comment: Yeah I totally missed that *blush*. Thanks!